# Fitting an image inside of a circle when the aspect ratio is not 1:1

Tags: css, image, positioning, aspect

I have a form where users upload an avatar of themselves.  Sometimes the file they upload is a perfect square, but often it's not.  Here's the HTML I'm using to display the image:

`<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px #000 solid; height: 70px; width: 70px;"/>`

And here's how it turns out depending on the aspect ratio of the image they upload:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqYc7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrsSu.png)

What I would like to achieve:

- The circle is full, so if the image they upload is the wrong aspect ratio or too small, it zooms to fill the circle.
- The image is centered, so that if they upload a gigantic image, it doesn't just show the top corner where their face is not in the frame.

Is there a good way to do this and account for many different scenarios of image sizes?

I've tried everything!

Comment: Look up object-fit.

Comment: ...and possibly `object-position`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `object-fit` and `object-position`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.i1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<img class="i0" src="http://picsum.photos/id/219/220/140">
<img class="i1" src="http://picsum.photos/id/219/220/140">
```